# How to connect to the Lua account status table

Tags: lua, binding

How can I connect to the Lua account status table so that the robot accesses or takes information from this table? My English is very bad, I hope my question will be understood

Comment: there are no account status tables in Lua nor can you connect to Lua tables. please name the API you're using. provide some code. it is not clear what you are referring to

Comment: What game you are writing Lua script for?

Comment: This is not about your English, you need to provide more details. Currently your question is unanswerable.